# Terraform destroy removes provider before removing dependent resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, provider

Background:
I am working on destroying a feature branch that contains a cross domain dependency in AWS (us-west-2 deploy dependency on a us-east-1 resource)  The project depends on a SNS topic subscription for a local region SQS queue and so I added a us-east-1 provider to allow the deploy to complete without errors.

Problem:
When the feature branch is no longer needed I want to perform a terraform destroy on the AWS resources created (lambda, queue, and east-1 topic subscription) but tf errors with the below error:

```
│ Error: Provider configuration not present
│ 
│ To work with aws_sns_topic_subscription.els_event_subscription (orphan) its
│ original provider configuration at
│ provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].sns2sqs is required, but it
│ has been removed. This occurs when a provider configuration is removed
│ while objects created by that provider still exist in the state. Re-add the
│ provider configuration to destroy
│ aws_sns_topic_subscription.els_event_subscription (orphan), after which you
│ can remove the provider configuration again.
```

The terraform code

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "sns2sqs"
  region = "us-east-1"

    default_tags {
        tags = {
          "<some-tags>" = ""
        }
    }

    ignore_tags {
        key_prefixes = ["<some_prefix>"]
    }
}

# The failing topic subscription
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "els_event_subscription" {
  provider               =  aws.sns2sqs
  topic_arn              = "${var.environment}" == "prod" ? "${var.els_sns_topics["prod"]}" : "${var.els_sns_topics["dev"]}"
  protocol               = "sqs"
  endpoint               = "${some-endpoint.arn}"
  endpoint_auto_confirms = true
  filter_policy          = jsonencode(var.event_filter_policy)
}
```

Comment: Are you deleting the file before running `terraform destroy`?

Comment: No files are being deleted just running a terraform destroy.  Things I have already tried: Adding depends_on's, adding lifecycle{prevent_destroy=true}, and using cli -target=aws_sns_topic_subscription.els_event_subscription none of these work.

Comment: The error is really strange, because Terraform doesn't "remove" the provider. The provider is just a configuration block, not an infrastructure resource that is created/updated/deleted by Terraform. The way I read the error message, it is not saying Terraform removed the provider, Terraform is actually accusing you of removing it. As if you had specifically removed the `provider` block from the .tf file, while resources still in the .tf file (and in the Terraform state file) referenced that provider.

Comment: I found a resolution to this, we use cake scripts to run the tf cli commands and our destroy is setup to run in a temp directory.  Well someone named the providers.tf file without the 's' "provider.tf" and the script looked for one named providers.tf hence no providers.tf file and no us-east-1 provider so Mark B as luck would have it you almost nailed.  TY

Comment: It sounds like I nailed it exactly, that you were removing the `provider` block. I obviously had no way of knowing that you had a script moving .tf files around like that, that was leaving the entire file out, since you didn't mention that script in your question. My first comment asking if you were deleting the file before running `terraform destroy` was actually what you were doing.